# Can I Use TestFlight Beta Testing for Apps Not Created Using Xcode?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, xcode, mac-appstore

I just submitted my enrollment application to be an Apple Developer.

I have three Mac 3D Puzzle apps that were created using Unity 5.3.2 that I plan to sign and submit to the Mac App Store after I'm approved as an Apple Developer. I have .app executable files created, not Xcode projects.

I'm new to Xcode. I'm currently taking the [iOS Development in Swift course by Plymouth University](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/ios-development-in-swift-timeline/id950659946) recommended by Apple. When you create a new Xcode project one of the options is OS X which I'm thinking is for creating Mac apps. I assume the course will cover uploading apps to the iTunes App Store.

On other platforms such as Amazon and the Windows App Store their websites specifically mention that apps submitted will be tested before they are approved. I did not find anything about submitted apps being tested other than the documentation on the [What's Included link](https://developer.apple.com/programs/whats-included/) about the **TestFlight Beta Testing** program. The text on this link mentions testing for iOS and tvOS apps. When you click the Learn more link it mentions iOS, watchOS and tvOS, not Mac.

The documentation says on the page that displays after Clicking Learn more: "To get your app ready for testers, upload a beta build of your app from Xcode and add the names and email address of people that you’d like to test in iTunes Connect." Is the **TestFlight Beta Testing** program only for testing apps that are written using Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

No, is not necessary. You can upload your app from both Xcode or Application Loader.

> Application Loader is a tool to help you upload your apps to iTunes
>   Connect. It’s particularly helpful if your app includes In-App
>   Purchase products that need to be configured for the app. Application
>   Loader is explained in [Using Application Loader](http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/). Application Loader is
>   available from the Resources and Help section of iTunes Connect.

With that tool you will be able to upload your .ipa file. Once your app is upload, you can distribute that build over Test Flight.

Comment: I've only used iTunes Connect for digital books. I don't have My Apps on my iTunes Connect home page so I guess I will have to wait until I'm approved as a developer to install it. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I checked where I can access Application Loaded through Xcode. I tried to log into my account and the software told me that I do not have the proper contracts signed so I definitely will have to wait.

Comment: You need to create you app on iTunes connect to upload it. And yes, you need your developer account to do it.

Comment: thanks! I just became an Apple Developer. I plan to try Application Loader with my three mac apps.